# tcl scripts, struggling with [...] and [expr ...]

Tags: tcl

I can't understand how assignments and use of variables work in Tcl.

Namely:

If I do something like

```
set a 5
set b 10
```

and I do

```
set c [$a + $b]
```

Following what internet says:

> You obtain the results of a command by placing the command in square
>   brackets (`[]`). This is the functional equivalent of the back single
>   quote (`` ` ``) in sh programming, or using the return value of a function
>   in C.

So my statement should set `c` to `15`, right?
If yes, what's the difference with

```
set c [expr $a + $b]
```

?
If no, what does that statement do?

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's a really strict language at its core; it *always follows the rules*. For your case, we can therefore analyse it like this:

```
set c [$a + $b]
```

That's three words, `set` (i.e., the standard “write to a variable” command), `c`, and what we get from evaluating the contents of the brackets in `[$a + $b]`. That in turn is a script formed by a single command invocation with another three words, the contents of the `a` variable (`5`), `+`, and the contents of the `b` variable (`10`). That the values look like numbers is irrelevant: the rules are the same in all cases.

Since you probably haven't got a command called `5`, that will give you an error. On the other hand, if you did this beforehand:

```
proc 5 {x y} {
    return "flarblegarble fleek"
}
```

then your script would “work”, writing some (clearly defined) utter nonsense words into the `c` variable. If you want to evaluate a somewhat mathematical expression, you use the `expr` command; that's it's one job in life, to concatenate all its arguments (with a space between them) and evaluate the result as an expression using the documented little expression language that it understands.

You virtually always want to put braces around the expression, FWIW.

---

There are other ways to make what you wrote do what you expect, but don't do them. They're slow. OTOH, if you are willing to put the `+` first, you can make stuff go fast with minimum interference:

```
# Get extra commands available for Lisp-like math...
namespace path ::tcl::mathop

set c [+ $a $b]
```

If you're not a fan of Lisp-style prefix math, use `expr`. It's what most Tcl programmers do, after all.

Comment: Seriously, `unknown` handlers have a big performance impact. Don't use them if you don't have to…

Answer (score 1):

```
set c [$a + $b]
```

Running the above command, you will get `invalid command name "5"` error message.

For mathematical operations, we should rely on `expr` only as `Tcl` treats everything as string.

```
set c [expr $a + $b]
```

In this case, the value of `a` and `b` is passed and addition is performed.

Here, it is always safe and recommended to brace the expressions as,

```
set c [expr {$a+$b}]
```

To avoid any possible surprises in the evaluation.

**Update 1 :**

In `Tcl`, everything is based on commands. It can a user-defined `proc` or existing built-in commands such as `lindex`. Using a bare-word of string will trigger a command call. Similarly, usage of `[` and `]` will also trigger the same.

In your case, `$a` replaced with the value of the variable `a` and since they are enclosed within square brackets, it triggers command call and since there is no command with the name `5`, you are getting the error.

Comment: That's exactly the error I've got. Why it does return that error? what operations are performed?

Comment: `[5 + 10]` tries to run a command named `5` with arguments `+` and `10`.  There is no command named `5` as the error indicates.

Comment: So does it interpret the result of $a as string?

Comment: @user8469759 also, that's one of the unique (and wonderful) things about tcl, see [this article](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018).